# How to sort Column B to match with column A in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have 3 columns in Google Sheet.
Column A have 95 rows with value.
Column B and C have 500 rows with value:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I need to sort Column B to match with Column A.
Column C represent value associated with column B.
So After sorting expected result should be like below pic (i only did for first 3 row but actually Column A and Column B will be identical for all of Column A's value - 95 rows)

How do I do this? I'm trying all sorts of sorting but nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that Column A and Column B have unique values:

1. Filter Column B to match the elements of Column A
2. Sort Column A and Column B using the same criteria

Built-in Google Sheets functions that could help you:

- Use FILTER or QUERY to filter values
- User SORT or QUERY to sort values

Another alternative is to use Google Apps Script, for details checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets